# Does the Radeon 58xx series support composite video output?

Tags: video, graphics-card, s-video

Does anyone know if the new ATI Radeon 5870/5850 cards still support composite or s-video output? For those of us with old/prehistoric TV's this is still important. I only read that there is VGA output via an adapter, but could not find any other information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you'll need a **[VGA to Video Converter](http://search.dell.ie/1/2/5458-startech-com-vga-to-tv-video-converter-with-remote-control-scan-converter.html)** to convert a VGA signal to Composite Video or S-Video.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. But I was hoping that composite support was just not explicitly mentioned in the card features and that it might be supported via a passive adapter.